# Boost Singleton Pool release_memory vs purge_memory

Tags: c++, boost, boost-pool

Where can I find the difference between `purge_memory` and `release_memory` in Boost Singleton Pool? In [here](https://valelab4.ucsf.edu/svn/3rdpartypublic/boost/libs/pool/doc/interfaces.html) it says:

> Singleton Usage is the method where each Pool is an object with static duration; that is, it will not be destroyed until program exit. Pool objects with Singleton Usage may be shared; thus, Singleton Usage implies thread-safety as well. System memory allocated by Pool objects with Singleton Usage may be freed through `release_memory` or `purge_memory`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking a few links on your page leads [to this page](https://valelab4.ucsf.edu/svn/3rdpartypublic/boost/libs/pool/doc/interfaces/pool.html).

There you can read the following:

```
t.release_memory()  bool    t must be ordered. Frees every memory block that doesn't have any
                allocated chunks. Returns true if at least one memory block was freed.

t.purge_memory()    bool    Frees every memory block. This function invalidates any pointers
                previously returned by allocation functions of t. Returns true if at
                least one memory block was freed.
```